# How to update a certain file from a branch to my forked repo

Tags: git, github

We have the central repo on github named:

```
topproject/aaa-work
```

(There are some other repo under `topproject` , like `bbb-work` that I don't use for now)

I have the git account "tom" and forked the repo, so the forked one like

```
tom/aaa-work
(forked from topproject/aaa-work)
```

My colleague "Jerry" has a similiar fork, she updated the file `readme` and made a pull request. For her updated file, I see following info on github.com

```
jerry/aaa-wrok
(fored from topproject/aaa-work)

branch update-readme    aaa-work/readme

----code in "readme"----
```

Question: I want to have her "readme" from her branch to my repo `tom/aaa-work`, how shall I do it?

Answer (score 0):

USE Gist : It is a simple way to share snippets and pastes with others. All gists are Git repositories, so they are automatically versioned, forkable and usable from Git.